# How to solve Execution failed for task ':expo-location:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm trying to run the expo project on android `expo run:android` and I get this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-location:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

The jdk version is 11

How can I solve this error?